# What evaluates to True/False in R?

Tags: r, boolean

For example, in Ruby, only nil and false are false.  What is what in R?

e.g.: `5==TRUE` and `5==FALSE` both evaluate to FALSE.  However, `1==TRUE` is `TRUE`. Is there any general rule as to what (objects, numbers, etc.) evaluate to?

Comment: Don't use `==` if you _really_ want to test for equivalence with `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If you use it, you are are doing a numerical comparison on the values that `TRUE` and `FALSE` coerce to. `isTRUE()` and `identical()` should be used if you really wan to know what is or is not `TRUE` or `FALSE`. See my answer for more.

Comment: Having `1==TRUE` evaluate to `TRUE` as a special case along with `0` for `FALSE` is a general rule in many programming languages, not just R. Possible reasons for this are the lack of a boolean type in C (the integers 0 and 1 are commonly substituted), and at a more basic level the fact that a single binary digit can represent a boolean value.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This is documented on `?logical`. The pertinent section of which is:

```
Details:

     ‘TRUE’ and ‘FALSE’ are reserved words denoting logical constants
     in the R language, whereas ‘T’ and ‘F’ are global variables whose
     initial values set to these.  All four are ‘logical(1)’ vectors.

     Logical vectors are coerced to integer vectors in contexts where a
     numerical value is required, with ‘TRUE’ being mapped to ‘1L’,
     ‘FALSE’ to ‘0L’ and ‘NA’ to ‘NA_integer_’.
```

The second paragraph there explains the behaviour you are seeing, namely `5 == 1L` and `5 == 0L` respectively, which should both return `FALSE`, where as `1 == 1L` and `0 == 0L` should be TRUE for `1 == TRUE` and `0 == FALSE` respectively. I believe these are not testing what you want them to test; the comparison is on the basis of the numerical representation of `TRUE` and `FALSE` in R, i.e. what numeric values they take when coerced to numeric.

However, only `TRUE` is guaranteed to the be `TRUE`:

```
> isTRUE(TRUE)
[1] TRUE
> isTRUE(1)
[1] FALSE
> isTRUE(T)
[1] TRUE
> T <- 2
> isTRUE(T)
[1] FALSE
```

`isTRUE` is a wrapper for `identical(x, TRUE)`, and from `?isTRUE` we note:

```
Details:
....

     ‘isTRUE(x)’ is an abbreviation of ‘identical(TRUE, x)’, and so is
     true if and only if ‘x’ is a length-one logical vector whose only
     element is ‘TRUE’ and which has no attributes (not even names).
```

So by the same virtue, only `FALSE` is guaranteed to be exactly equal to `FALSE`.

```
> identical(F, FALSE)
[1] TRUE
> identical(0, FALSE)
[1] FALSE
> F <- "hello"
> identical(F, FALSE)
[1] FALSE
```

If this concerns you, always use `isTRUE()` or `identical(x, FALSE)` to check for equivalence with `TRUE` and `FALSE` respectively. `==` is not doing what you think it is.

Comment: One more thing.  In an `if` condition, non-zero numbers are treated like `TRUE` and 0 is treated like `FALSE`.

Comment: @Richie: it's not just numbers; every condition is coerced to logical.  See my comment on Rafe's answer.

Answer (score 5):

`T` and `TRUE` are True, `F` and `FALSE` are False. `T` and `F` can be redefined, however, so you should only rely upon `TRUE` and `FALSE`. If you compare 0 to FALSE and 1 to TRUE, you will find that they are equal as well, so you might consider them to be True and False as well.

Comment: It's worth noting that only `TRUE` and `FALSE` are reserved.  `T` and `F` can be re-defined.  I.e. `T <- "hi"` is valid, while `TRUE <- "hi"` is an error.

Comment: Actually I was asking more about everything else.  For example, `1==TRUE` evaluates to TRUE, but `5==TRUE` and `5==FALSE` both evaluate to FALSE.  I can't find any documentation on what evaluates to true or false in general.

Comment: Actually, if you open your global `Rprofile` file, you'll see that `T` and `F` have `TRUE` and `FALSE` values assigned, accordingly.

Comment: @Ruby noob, and `0 == FALSE` evaluates to `TRUE`. =)

Comment: It's worth further noting that the opposite is true in S, where T and F are the reserved words and TRUE and FALSE can be redefined.  So it's best to use TRUE and FALSE always in R, and to not reassign T and F.

Comment: Apearently any integer other then 0 is also evaluated as true: `if (5) print("true!")`

Comment: @Sacha: it's not just integers other than 0, and it's not because of evaluation (strictly speaking).  It's because `if` attempts to coerce the condition to logical (e.g. `if("True") print("true!")`).  See `?"if"` and `?as.logical` for more information.

Answer (score -1):

If you think about it, comparing numbers to logical statements doesn't make much sense. However, since **0 is often associated with "Off" or "False"** and **1 with "On" or "True"**, R has decided to allow `1 == TRUE` and `0 == FALSE` to both be true. Any other numeric-to-boolean comparison should yield false, unless it's something like `3 - 2 == TRUE`.

Comment: `as.logical(3.2)` returns TRUE.