# Comparing integers with characters in R

Tags: r

It appears that `as.character()` of a number is still a number, which I find counter intuitive. Consider this example:

```
1 > "2"
[1] FALSE
2 > "1"
[1] TRUE
```

Even if I try to use `as.character()` or `paste()`

```
as.character(2)
[1] "2"
as.character(2) > 1
[1] TRUE
as.character(2) < 1
[1] FALSE
```

Why is that? Can't I have R return an error when I am comparing numbers with strings?

Comment: **as.character represents real and complex numbers to 15 significant digits** <== From the docs. Maybe use an `expression` instead? What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: @NelsonGon this behavior caused some problem in a lengthy function. I was not expecting comparison between numbers and characters would throw an error, but didn't.

Comment: This probably answers the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932015/why-true-true-is-true-in-r The important part is `If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of precedence being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and raw.`

Comment: You might want to check out `"2" > 11`. The reason why this works as it does is basically the same as why `paste0("A", 1)` or `1L + 0.1` works. R changes the types when needed.

Comment: If as.character indeed forms numbers, what then is the hierarchy in this case? Is it a case of doing what comparison does(coerce) or simply as.character returning a numeric and the comparison made based on that? @Roland

Comment: @NelsonGon `as.character` of course creates characters. What than happens is that `>` coerces the number to `character` and these characters are compared according to the collating sequence as the documentation explains.

Comment: Thanks. Just a bit confused. The documentation for `as. character` talks of some representation of real and complex numbers so I naively thought what would happen would be for as.charcater to form an integer repr of the string and then this would be used for comparison. I must have misunderstood that. @Roland

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation of `?Comparison` states that

> If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of precedence being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and raw.

So in your case the number is automatically coerced to string and the comparison is made based on the respective collation.

In order to prevent it, the only option I know of is to manually compare the `class` first.

Answer (score 4):

As explained in the comments the problem is that the numeric 1 is coerced to character.
The operation `<` still works for characters. A character is smaller than another if it comes first in alphabetical order.

```
> "a" < "b"
[1] TRUE
> "z" < "b"
[1] FALSE
```

So in your case `as.character(2) > 1` is transformed to `as.character(2) > as.character(1)` and because of the "alphabetical" order of numbers `TRUE`is returned.

To prevent this you would have to check for the class of an object manually.