# How OR operator works

Tags: r, logical-operators

I am new to R. *I want to confirm if my understanding of the concept is correct.*

While working with logical operator OR I am unable to understand the below output. Case 1 has result "false" when both the second elements as 0 while it is "true" when these are numbers >0. Is this because 0 is always considered as "FAlse" and in this case both these values are "false"?

**Case 1**

```
v <- c(3,0,TRUE,2+2i)
t <- c(4,0,FALSE,2+3i)
print(v|t)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

---

**Case 2**

```
v <- c(3,0,TRUE,2+2i)
t <- c(3,0,FALSE,2+3i)
print(v|t)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: You should read the documentation. Numeric values other than 0 are converted to TRUE if used as logical values

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681166/what-evaluates-to-true-false-in-r for more details

Answer (score 2):

You are doing an elementwise logical comparison of both vectors v and t. And since any number > 0 evaluates to `TRUE` if converted to logical you are getting this output. (please also note the comment below)

You can think of this happenig in the background (for **case 1**):

```
   as.logical(3) | as.logical(4)
   as.logical(0) | as.logical(0)
            TRUE | TRUE
as.logical(2+2i) | as.logical(2+2i)
```

which yields our output:

```
TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: not only numbers > 0, also `isTRUE(as.logical(-5))` and `isTRUE(as.logical(-Inf))`

Answer (score 1):

R considers TRUE as 1 and FALSE as 0. Your understanding is correct. You have an elementwise checking and in the case where `v[2]=0` and `t[2]=0`, R understands: `0 | 0` thus 0, i.e. `FALSE OR FALSE = FALSE`.

You can check this by changing one of the 0 inputs (v[2]=0 and t[2]=0) to something `!=0`.

As a comment though: 
you have to take into account that you can not use `c()` to create variables with different classes in them. R interprets all the inputs that you provide as complex numbers in this case. I mean that the `TRUE` is converted to `1+0i` and the FALSE to `0+0i` (check the:
`print(v)`
`>v`
`[1] -3+0i  0+0i  1+0i  0+2i`)